# Is it possible to get the ActivityContext outside the workflow?

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

Im working with a workflow solution. In this workflow i have an Argument that keep specific data in order inside the workflow.

To host my solution I use WorkflowApplication instance that I call _workflowApplication.

If I take _workflowApplication.WorkflowDefinition as MyActivity I get the activity.

In this activity I have my argument that I need outside the workflow now but to get that argument I need to have an ActivityContext to send in.

Is it possible to get this context or do someone knows another good way to get out that kind of data from the workflow?

Edit1:
The WF is hosted in Azure and is using Persistance against an SQL Azure Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is something called ***Tracking***.

You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513992%28v=VS.110%29.aspx).

If you want to get your hands directly into the code I advise you to download [these](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21459) samples, more specifically in the **WF_WCF_Samples\WF\Basic\Tracking** folder there are a handful of examples. I guess some of them are exactly what you want to do.

It really is a pretty simple concept once you get how it works.

Comment: Tracking seems to be a good solution for my problem. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

One possible method for getting data into/from the workflow is by using Extensions.
You can look at [this blog](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1091-workflow-foundation-40-extension-.aspx) for a sample of how you can use Extensions.